# how to update values on axes of point chart in c#

Tags: c#

In my project im having a point chart .For each and every 1 second time interval im updating the values in the points chart that's works fine.But while updating the values it is automatically splitting 4 values on x axis like 1,2,3,4 (1,2,3,4 are x axis values).But i want 10 fixed values to be plot on x axis.How to do it?

Please refer my code below ,

```
series.Name = "Series";
series.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
series.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
series.IsXValueIndexed = true;
series.YAxisType=AxisType.Primary;
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;

this.chart.Series.Add(series);
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "X Axis value";
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Y Axis value1";
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Title = "Y Axis value2";

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Size = 15;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.All;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = false;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(2,3);

chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;

chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
```

Comment: existing and expected images

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want your x axis shows 0-10 range:
Try add follow code：

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 10;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
```

Comment: I tried this one,It is working fine with out horizontal scroll bar. If I implement scroll bar only 4 values coming on x-axis.How to do?

Comment: I used below code to enable scroll bar. chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Size = 15;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.All;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = false;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(2,3);

Comment: seems you figure it out by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> If you use horizontal scroll bar for your chart,use the following code to display 10 intervals on x-axis.

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(2, 9);
```